# How to get Git Push to only push commit created in current branch instead of including all commits from master?

Tags: git, branch, pull-request

So I have...

- A remote upstream repo
- A remote origin repo (which is forked from upstream)
- My local repo

Right now, from local master branch, when running either of these commands, the response I get is "Already up to date."

```
git pull upstream master

git pull origin master
```

My steps are:

- In master branch, when I run 'git log', a long list of commits are returned.
- 'git checkout -b new_branch' to go from master into a branch where I'm going to do my work.
- In my new_branch, I run 'git log' again and the same commits are returned. HEAD of new_branch is at the latest commit from master.
- I edit a file, add, and commit it. 'git log' shows this new commit at the top of the list.
- I do 'git push origin new_branch'.

The push takes all the commits from master and includes them in the pull request. I've tried 'git rebase -i HEAD~' to drop the other commits, except the list is too long to edit (100s of commits). This isn't a new environment and I've had other branches which worked fine. I normally checkout to master before creating a new branch. Not sure why this started to happen today.

Comment: Against which branch are you trying to create the Pull Request? It is normal to take all the commits from master as you are working on top of it but if you create the PR against master branch it should only show the latest commit which you have added.

Comment: @Deep My PR is always meant to be against the same remote origin branch matching the name of my local branch. So it's never meant to be pushed to master.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the issue you are facing, as the steps you are following seems to be correct and should not give issues.